# Web application needs an alternate URL or 'extended web application'

Tags: wss-3.0, alternate-access-mapping

On final migration day, I'll be removing the name from our old WSS 3.0 server (http://sharepoint.domain.com) and placing it on our SharePoint 2010 server.  I'd still like to be able to access our old server at a URL just in case there are issues.  I tried to Extend the Web App on our WSS 3.0 server, however, Service Unavailable was reported for all URLs (old & new).  I got it working (with help from this forum - thank you!) but not with the Extended Web App in place.  Had to back it out.  Is there another way to access the server (perhaps using server name & port?) or do I need to set aside some server downtime where I can troubleshoot the Extended Web App/Service Unavailable issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a pretty simple solution.  Merely have your DNS folks whip up a new DNS entry (like http://sharepoint07.domain.com - note the 07 in there), point that to your current 07 server and then add that as the URL for one of your Zones in your Alternate Access Mappings( I.E. Intranet/Internet/Extranet/Custom).

When the migration happens, http://sharepoint.domain.com can move over to 2010 without any fuss and you can continue to access your 07 site on the new http://sharepoint07.domain.com url for as long as it is needed.

If you have fiddled with the settings in IIS, you may need to also add the sharepoint07.domain.com as one of the valid host headers for your SP 07 site.

Comment: Nice!!  Thanks.  So it's not necessary to "Extend the Web App" as well?

Comment: Correct.  The Alternate Access Mapping handles what it sounds like you were attempting to do by extending the web app.

Comment: First off - thanks fo much for your replies.  And after I put more thought into it, I'm unsure how this will work for our setup.  Under AAM, I have two URLs - one for CA and one for our only Web App http://sharepoint.domain.com under Internal URL, Zone is Default and Public URL is http://sharepoint.domain.com.  If I setup another, doesn't it have to point to http://sharepoint.domain.com (which will disappear on final migration day).  My apologies for not giving enough detail originally.

Comment: I have to admit that I am a little unclear on this comment. However, AAMs only tell sharepoint what to listen to - they do not tell your network which server hosts that URL as that is a function of your DNS server.  Both the old and the new farm can listen to http://sharepoint.domain.com but your DNS will dictate where traffic gets routed.  When the switchover happens, just update your DNS to point to the new server

Comment: After re-reading my comment, I can understand why you were unclear.  Sorry!  This afternoon in testing, I setup http://sharepoint07.domain.com on our DNS server and then created the AAM (Internal URL: http://sharepoint07.domain.com, Zone: Default and Public URL for Zone is showing http://sharepoint.domain.com).  When I point my browser to http://sharepoint07.domain.com, it works but it immediately redirects to http://sharepoint.domain.com.  This will conflict with our new farm once http://sharepoint.domain.com is moved to it, won't it?

Comment: The sharepoint07.domain.com url needs to be defined as the default url for one of your zones.  If it is simply an AAM to your sharepoint.domain.com then it will do the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: This can't be done in advance, correct?  If I understand it correctly, I'll have to wait until the day our SharePoint 2010 server goes live as the sharepoint07.domain.com will replace sharepoint.domain.com as our Default.

Comment: For clarification, I'll assume your Extranet zone is unused.  Set sharepoint07.domain.com as the default URL for that zone.  You may also have to modify IIS to pass the sharepoint07.domain.com to sharepoint.  Once that is done, you can access your current production 07 site using either sharepoint.domain.com or sharepoint07.domain.com.  Note that any hard-coded links or redirects in the pages may cause you to hop back to sharepoint.domain.com while browsing so you will need to keep an eye out for that.  That is a content issue, not a SharePoint issue.

Comment: When the time comes to go live, simply update your DNS and point the url sharepoint.domain.com to point to the new 2010 server instead.  You will still be able to access the old server at SharePoint07.domain.com.

Comment: Also, I am assuming that your physical sharepoint server is not called 'sharepoint'.  If that is the case then I strongly advise you to come up with a different URL.  The only time you should ever access a SharePoint server using the machine name is 1) Central Admin and 2) to access a specific server for testing in a load balanced environment.

Comment: Thanks for your patience in explaining this. I apologize for not grasping it entirely. You've explained it well but something still eludes me. At the risk of embarrassing myself, I've included a screenshot of our [AAM](http://www.acadiau.ca/~tammy/aam.png).  I don't understand how when I create sharepoint07.domain.com, it will know where to go once sharepoint.domain.com is gone.  It seems that when I create/add it, it points to the existing web app (sharepoint.domain.com) but that name will no longer be on that server.

Comment: After thought - Perhaps this is where [Internal URL](http://www.acadiau.ca/~tammy/internal%20url.png) it's setup?  That way it points to the "Default Web Site" as opposed to the name sharepoint.domain.com?

Comment: Click on "Edit Public URLs" and then add your SharePoint2007.domain.com url to one of the blank zones, i.e. Extranet.  Once you've done that, you should be able to use either URL to access your site

Comment: And now that it's in place, I understand how it works.  Thank you!